# Change custom postType properties from parent theme in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm building a childtheme for an excisting Wordpress theme.
The parent theme creates a custom post type, that has a property "rewrite" property that I would like to get rid of.

```js
'rewrite' => array(
 'slug' => 'project'
)
```

I found that it is possible to alter / add taxonomies on excisting custom post types like this:
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'CUSTOM_POST_NAME' );

But is it posible to change this (and other) properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is the call to [`register_post_type`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/). This is what actually registers the post type within WordPress.

In the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#source), we see that the function is defined in `/wp-includes/post.php`. We can also see the full source code of the function, which is very handy.

In the source code of the function, we can see that there's only a single `do_action()` and that's called after the post type is fully registered.

So, the next place to look at is in the [`WP_Post_Type`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post_type/) class. We can again expand the full source code(or you can look through the source code in your favorite text/code editor). The first place to look at is the `__construct()` method of the class. This currently(WordPress 4.8) consists of the following:

```
public function __construct( $post_type, $args = array() ) {
    $this->name = $post_type;

    $this->set_props( $args );
}
```

So, as you can see, the name is assigned to `$this->name` and then the method `set_props()` is called with the passed `$args`(which is the array of parameters sent to `register_post_type()`.

The next logical place to look at is inside of the `set_props()` method. And at pretty much the very top of that method is the following code:

```
    /**
     * Filters the arguments for registering a post type.
     *
     * @since 4.4.0
     *
     * @param array  $args      Array of arguments for registering a post type.
     * @param string $post_type Post type key.
     */
    $args = apply_filters( 'register_post_type_args', $args, $this->name );
```

Bingo! The passed `$args` are passed through the `register_post_type_args` filter before they're used in initializing the post type.

So now, the final piece of the puzzle is to create your own function, attach it to the `register_post_type_args` filter, make sure you're changing the correct post type and you're free to do whatever you want with that post type. Here's a sample code to help you out:

```
function my_filter_register_post_type_args( $args, $post_type ) {
    // We only want to edit the 'CUSTOM_POST_NAME' post type - if that's not it, then bail
    if ( 'CUSTOM_POST_NAME' != $post_type ) {
        return $args;
    }

    $args['rewrite'] = false;

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'my_filter_register_post_type_args', 10, 2 );
```

---

I hope this will help you and anyone else out there see how easy it can be to dive into the source code of WordPress(you can even do it from your browser now :) ) in order to figure out something that might not always be just a search away. With some critical thinking, you can follow the breadcrumb trail in order to figure out what the best way to tweak something is.